# Elm -- parse text file into Html

Tags: html, parsing, csv, elm

I'm very new to Elm (and newish to FP in general) I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to do certain things.

I'm using ports currently to read in a text file and pass it off to elm (index.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Show the stamp module in the "elm-div" div.
  var div = document.getElementById('elm-div');
  var golf = Elm.embed(Elm.Golf, div, { reset:[], openFromFile: "" });

  var upload = document.getElementById('fileinput');

  upload.onchange = function (e) {
      reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (event) {
          data = event.target.result;
          //file's text data is sent to 'openfromfile' port
          golf.ports.openFromFile.send(data);
          }
      reader.readAsText(upload.files[0]);
      };
</script>
```

Golf.elm (so far):

```
module Golf where

import Html exposing (Html, Attribute, text, toElement, div, input)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Color exposing (..)
import Signal exposing ((<~),(~))
import String

port reset : Signal ()   
port openFromFile : Signal String

getLines : Signal (List String)
getLines = String.lines <~ openFromFile
```

I'm having trouble thinking about how the Golf.elm file should be structured. I have text data in a CSV format (delimited by ',') where:

```
"Round Number", "Par", "steve", "kyle", "rick"
1, 3, 5, 8, 1
2, 5, 3, 7, 8
3, 4, 6, 5, 4
4, 3, 2, 4, 3
5, 2, 5, 7, 4
```

What I want to do is read the CSV and show an html table with the scores relative to par for each player/round (score= number - par) but The fact that I'm starting not with a regular model in record format but a `Signal (List String)` has me completely lost.

I sent my `getLines` back through ports to `console.log` it so I know I'm reading the file correctly and generating a `Signal (List String)` properly from the text source but I have no where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

You may start with types:

```
type alias CSV = { headers : Maybe (List String)
                 , records : List  (List String)
                 }
```

You have:

```
getLines : Signal (List String)
```

but needs:

```
getCSV   : Signal CSV
```

Use core [Signal.map](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#map):

```
map : (a -> result) -> Signal a -> Signal result
```

Then type signature will be (a = `List String`, result = `CSV`):

```
map0     : (List String -> CSV) -> Signal (List String) -> Signal CSV
```

Missing part is:

```
parseCSV : List String -> CSV
```

Combine all things together:

```
getCSV : Signal CSV
getCSV = Signal.map parseCSV getLines
```

## Result

```
-- ...

getCSV : Signal CSV
getCSV = Signal.map badParseCSV getLines

type alias CSV = { headers : Maybe (List String)
                 , records : List  (List String)
                 }

badParseCSV : List String -> CSV
badParseCSV xs =
  let parseLine = List.map (trimQuotes << String.trim)
              <<  String.split ","
      trimQuotes x = if String.startsWith "\"" x 
                     && String.endsWith "\"" x
                     then String.dropRight 1 <| String.dropLeft 1 x
                     else x
      records0 = List.map parseLine
              <| List.filter (\x -> not (String.isEmpty x))
              <| List.drop 1 xs
      headers0 = Maybe.map parseLine <| List.head xs
  in  { headers = headers0
      , records = records0}

view : CSV -> Html
view csv =
  let rows    = List.map (\xs -> Html.tr [] (cols xs)) csv.records
      cols xs = List.map col xs
      col  x  = Html.td [] [ text x]
      ths  xs = List.map (\x -> Html.th [] [text x]) xs
      headers = Maybe.withDefault [] <| Maybe.map ths csv.headers
  in Html.table [] [ Html.thead [] headers
                   , Html.tbody [] rows
                   ]

main : Signal Html
main = Signal.map view getCSV
```

Comment: I'm confused by a few things, 

firstly I'm not too familiar with the function composition syntax. for example in this line:

Comment: List.map (trimQuotes << String.trim)
              <<  String.split ","

what is that equivalent to? I thought it would be:
List.map (trimQuotes (String.trim xs)) (String.split "," xs) but it looks like that's incorrect.

I'm having a problem wrapping my head around how you were able to take the Signal (List String) and drop the signal part of it so that you could end up with something more usable.

Comment: you may start with `map (\x -> f2 (f1 x)) list` 

equivalent to `map (\x -> f2 <| f1 x) list` 

and to `map (\x -> f1 x |> f2) list` 
and with composition `map (f2 << f1) list` or `map (f1 >> f2) list`

Comment: Signal part not dropped, but "modified" (creates new value wrapped in Signal).

`List.map f list  -- List a => List b`,
`Signal.map f signal     -- Signal a => Signal b`,
`Maybe.map f val `       -- Maybe a => Maybe b

Comment: `parseLine        = List.map (trimQuotes << String.trim) << String.split ","`  =>
`parseLine1       = List.map (\x -> trimQuotes ( String.trim x)) << String.split ","` =>
`parseLine2  xs = List.map (\x -> trimQuotes ( String.trim x)) (String.split "," xs)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response and follow up, also thank you for not giving me the 'full' solution, I used your answer to create a CSV with record : List (List Int) that contained the correct score for each player. Your help was invaluable.